# Red Hat JBoss BPM Suite - Data provider field in select box

Tags: jboss, redhat, jbpm, business-process-management, redhat-bpm

I'm trying to create a select box inside a new form definition that show options catched from an external DB (MySQL). I already tried to use this "Data provider" field but it's always empty, even if I configure a new "Data sets" with my external DB...
Or, maybe, there is another solution?

Someone could help me?
Thanks :)

As you can see, this field with the red dot is empty .-.

[image: As you can see, this field with the red dot is empty .-.]

Answer (score 0):

A data provider is a java class the implement `org.jbpm.formModeler.core.config.SelectValuesProvider` interface.

1. Create that implementation
2. Build the project and place the jar in the Business Central libraries (META-INF/lib)
3. You'll find the data provider in the selector.

Here an example: [RestDataProvider](https://github.com/dmarrazzo/rh-bpm-notes/tree/master/samples/forms/RestDataProvider)

In the Java code, you can place your logic to retrive the list from a SQL DB.